# Как растянуть блок во всю высоту?

Tags: html, css

Как можно растянуть блок .table-items-name , чтобы его высота была равна .table-items-parametr и наоборот ?

```
<div class="table-items"> 
  <div class="table-items-name"> 
    <p>Язык текста</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-items-parameter"> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia omnis nemo minima asperiores aspernatur quae molestiae ab, eveniet veniam corporis. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia omnis nemo minima asperiores aspernatur quae molestiae ab, eveniet veniam corporis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Код тут [click](https://codepen.io/kah3vich/pen/BawWvYB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
align-items: stretch;
```

align-items растянет детей внутри flex, но только если у детей не фиксировано height

Посмотри здесь: [click](https://codepen.io/viyfbqtg-the-selector/pen/BawWvXo)

Comment: пример кода имеет смысл вставить непосредственно в ответ (при редактировании есть кнопка вставки «фрагмент кода на javascript/html/css»).

Comment: Спасибки большое )